# Accessing a hyperfileSQL data via #

Tags: c#, hyperfilesql

I have an application designed by WinDev, and it stores its data in hyperfilesSql files. What I want to do, is to extract these data using a C# application.

I tried to find a OleDb Provider for these hyperfilesSql, but with no result. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how do to it ^^ :

1 : You can get the OleDb Provider for hyperfileSql files from this [page](http://www.pcsoft.fr/st/telec/modules-communs-15/wx15_63j.htm).

2 : Here is a simple exemple of the code used to extract data :

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=PCSOFT.HFSQL;Initial Catalog=C:\MyDataFolder";
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM MyTable"; //MyTable = The .FIC file

DataTable table = new DataTable();

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
       using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection))
       {
              adapter.Fill(table); //Fill the table with the extracted data
       }
}

gridControl1.DataSource = table; //Set the DataSource of my grid control
```

For other connection strings : visite the [page](http://doc.pcsoft.fr/fr-FR/?9000059)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Is it possible to join to other tables? I get an error when I do SELECT * From Mytable INNER JOIN OtherTable ON Mytable.SomeId = OtherTable.SomeId

Comment: @ErikDekker : Hi, frankly, I did not try it, but here is a web page that may help you : http://doc.pcsoft.fr/en-us/?2034007